# Get Selection of ComboBoxPropertyDescriptor in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, properties, jface

I am writing an Eclipse plugin in java and now I want to use a [ComboBoxPropertyDescriptor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/ComboBoxPropertyDescriptor.html)

```
public class MyComboBoxDescriptor extends ComboBoxPropertyDescriptor {

public MyComboBoxDescriptor(Object id, String displayName) {
    super(id, displayName, new String[]{"value1", "value2", "value3"});
}
```

How can I get the selected value at runtime?

Comment: Not specifically related to your question, but did you noticed the comment in the javadocs _This class may be instantiated; it is not intended to be subclassed._ ?  If you want to build your own, you should probably implement [IPropertyDescriptor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/IPropertyDescriptor.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the PropertySheet and your own org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource implementation, the standard ComboBoxPropertyDescriptor should tell the property source when the value is selected.